# What does the property "-fx-background-insets" mean and all means of its params

Tags: css, javafx

What does every parameter of property "-fx-background-insets" perform on the "BUTTON"'s style?
I'm using JavaFX recently.And when I change the parameter "2" to "200",button's style looks like nothing different.

```
.button{    
-fx-background-insets: 0 0 0 0, 0, 1, 2;
}
```

Comment: @scrovor - from your question whe **cannot** decipher that you're using JavaFX 8 ;)... Hence why it's important you give enough information. Consider editing this and adding it to your question - also mention where you've already searched (and didn't find) an answer. This might help people to help you.

Comment: Hey @James_D, I'm terribly sorry, I misread this, when I was in *review* mode. I didn't want to plagiarize at all :)... I really didn't see there was already an answer. Hence, I'll upvote your answer, my bad! Hope you understand. I've also removed those comments, because they're irrelevant.

Comment: Ah, OK, understood.

Comment: @YvesSchelpe Thanks for your attention and suggestion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region), these values are represented as

> A series of size values or sets of four size values, separated by commas. A single size value means all insets are the same. Otherwise, the four values for each inset are given in the order top, right, bottom, left. Each comma-separated value or set of values in the series applies to the corresponding background color.

So in your example, the insets apply to a series of four background colors (defined by four comma-separated values provided to the `-fx-background-color` property).

The first has zero insets on all fours sides (explicitly stated as a list of four zeros).

The second also has zero insets on all four sides (defined using a shorthand of a single zero value).

The third and fourth have insets of one pixel and two pixels, respectively, again defined using the single value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I had read the docs of it.I also has tried to change the number "1" and "2" to a large number,but why don't I see it changes obviously?My English is poor :)...

Comment: @Scrovor What is your actual question? Is it "what do these values mean?", or is it "why doesn't my code do what I expect?". If your question is the second one, you need to actually ask that question: provide the code, explain what you want it to do, etc. Read how to create a [MCVE].

Comment: Thanks for your patient.I think it is the second question now.When I change the value “2” to "200",the button looks nothing changed.                    The codes likes this:    `.button {
    -fx-border-color: #e2e2e2;
    -fx-border-width: 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-color: #1d1d1d;
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    -fx-font-size: 10pt;
    -fx-text-fill: #d8d8d8;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 0 0, 0, 1, 200;
    -fx-text-alignment: center;
}`

Answer (score 17):

```
.custom-node {
-fx-background-color: skyblue, derive(skyblue, 25%), derive(skyblue, 50%), derive(skyblue, 75%);
-fx-background-insets: 20, 40, 60, 80;
-fx-border-color: red; /* set border to red*/
-fx-border-width: 3; /* border width 3px */
```

[image]

https://jojorabbitjavafxblog.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/javafx-2-0-css-styling-part-1/

ps: white is root background color

Comment: Thanks, It really helps.

Comment: The linked blog article is especially helpful.