# How to set background insets only for one side in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

This CSS code (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53204645/5057736)):

```
.custom-node {
    -fx-background-color: skyblue, derive(skyblue, 25%), derive(skyblue, 50%), derive(skyblue, 75%);
    -fx-background-insets: 20, 40, 60, 80;
    -fx-border-color: red; /* set border to red*/
    -fx-border-width: 3; /* border width 3px */
}
```

gives such result:

[image]

Now I want to have this "color ladder" only(!) for bottom side. So I set insets to

```
-fx-background-insets: 0, 0, 20 40 60 80, 0;
```

But it didn't work - the whole node is in one color. Could anyone say how to do it?

Comment: As you have working code and an image at hand, you can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).

Comment: How these properties work is documented [here](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have four background colors defined.

Each comma separated value for `-fx-background-insets` defines the inset for the respective background color.

```
-fx-background-color: skyblue, derive(skyblue, 25%), derive(skyblue, 50%), derive(skyblue, 75%);
-fx-background-insets: 0 0 20 0, 0 0 40 0, 0 0 60 0, 0 0 80 0;
```

The description of the syntax for background insets is in the [CSS reference](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region).

> A series of size values or sets of four size values, separated by commas. A single size value means all insets are the same. Otherwise, the four values for each inset are given in the order top, right, bottom, left. Each comma-separated value or set of values in the series applies to the corresponding background color.

Alternately, you could use a linear gradient and a single background.